# Python split strings inside of a list in a for loop

Tags: python

I created a list of addresses that looks like this:

> ['123 Home Court || 456 Jeopardy Lane',  '456 Jeopardy Lane || 789
>   Sesame Street',  '789 Sesame Street || 7221 Long Road']

I want to split them by the "||" in a for loop (it needs to be in a for loop because I want to do other work on the items), but it's not working the way I expected. I want to do this for each item in the list:

```
start, end = addresses[0].split('||')
```

But if I try:

```
for i in addresses:
    start, end = addresses[i].split('||')
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Can someone help me figure out how to properly do this in a for loop? Also, why is it giving me this error? Thanks for the help as always!

Comment: is `i` an int, or is it the actual cell.   *ponders*  What does it say when you print out what `i` is?  *hint* it's the actual cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case `i` is not an index, but one of the addresses. That means:

```
for address in addresses:
  start, end = address.split('||')
```

Comment: Typographical error. Should this be answered? I don't believe so.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It's not a typo, it's a misunderstanding of how `for` works.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's giving me this error now though:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @Emac Whatever it gives, it has nothing to do with this question. Please ask a new one. Or better still, better read the docs and tutorials on python syntax.

Comment: @Emac That means you have data in your list that does not contain a `||`

Comment: One problem solved, one to go? If this solved your initial problem then mark it as correct, then ask in relation to the next hurdle. This keeps things focused.

Comment: @Emac Considering that this solved the problem in your question, you should mark this question as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the help tadman. For anyone who finds this thread in the future, I solved the other problem I encountered with this:

for address in addresses:
    start, end = address.split('||')[0], address.split('||')[1]

Comment: Why not `start,end = address.split('||')[0:2]` if you want to take *only* two elements?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
for i in range(len(addresses)):
    start, end = addresses[i].split('||')
```

Comment: NOT better than the other solution. `for` loops excel in iterating over structures. It's a waste and lowers performance to iterate over indices and then reference again.

Comment: as Emac try using its index that's why I do this in way

Comment: OP doesn't always know what's best to use. Also, they were not using `range`.

Comment: I think one problem has a multiple solution. And first we have to learn then we should try to find the best. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind the goal here is to provide the answer that will benefit readers the most, not just list out every possible solution because you _can_. _Thanks_.